# Weird logcat: How to fix?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, stringbuffer

to see the version of Busybox use this code

public String busybox_v() throws IOException {

```
Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec("busybox");
    InputStream a = p.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(a);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;

    try {

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

    } finally {
        read.close();
        in.close();
    }

    String result = buffer.toString().substring(0, 15);
    return result;

}
```

In most phones work well, but in a Nexus 4 they sent me this logcat

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0;
>   regionLength=15 at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:583)
>   at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1464) at
>   com.MyPackage.MyApplicationName.Root.busybox_v(Root.java:98) at
>   com.MyPackage.MyApplicationName.PageFragment$1.onClick(PageFragment.java:101)
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) at
>   de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:110) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

The line 98 corresponds to the closing brace of the while. I can not understand how to solve this problem. Some help?

Comment: Probably `buffer` doesn't contain 16 chars (Note:  `at java.lang.String.substring`).

Comment: You cannot get an exception on a brace. Please double check the line number, or that you are executing the code you think you are.

Comment: Could be, ideas on how I can fix this? In an Activity I run this method inside a try-catch (IOExcepetion e)

Comment: @SimonePiglietti Check whether the `buffer` length is valid to `substring` it with `0` and `15`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely that your StringBuffer doesn't have 16 characters. You could try something like this:

```
String result = buffer.toString().substring(0, Math.min(buffer.length()-1,15));
```

To know more than that, the question becomes what is result trying to do? If it's a hex code, then maybe you should append 0's to the front in such case. If it's a string, maybe append spaces. Bottom line is, you should figure out what to do if you haven't inputed 16 characters, and act appropriately. This could be done by something like:

```
if (buffer.length()>=16)
{
    String result = buffer.toString().substring(0, 15);
}
else
{
    //Do something here to manage the exception
}
```

Comment: This will prevent the exception, but might ruin the logic and lead to wrong behavior of the program. If the `15` is critic, I prefer to have an `if` and manually check if it will exceed the `buffer` length.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Good point. Added a blurb about figuring out what to do if you don't have sufficient characters.

Comment: Running the command busybox, the first 16 characters return as a result "Busybox v1.21.1" then taking the first 16 characters i get the version. Have better ideas on how I can do?

Comment: You're trying to read a version number? I would do some sort of a regex to get the version number out, or perhaps just look for the character v and read what follows. In my opinion though, I would just ask a separate question on how to best do that, focusing on the string, language, and desired outputs.